# how to know when Map control was first manipulated?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using the Map control in Windows Phone 8.

I need to implement a page where user can select his location using the map control.
I am trying to know when the app was first manipulated by the user.

Some background info:
I saw that when the control is shown, it automatically centers the world map, and CenterChanged event is raised.
I am not able to understand how ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta and ManipulationCompleted work.
the first time I drag, ManipulationStarted is not called, only ManipulationCompleted.

I could consider the first manipulation by user as being the 2nd time the CenterChanged is fired.
But this is a hack or a guess, I am not happy not having a good understanding how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The Map control intercepts and handles Manipulation events and as such you don't get all of them. Remember, once routed events are marked at e.Handled=true they no longer bubble up.

Depending on your Scenario WP8 exposes the [UseOptimizedManipulationRouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property which might prove useful. Setting UseOptimizedManipulationRouting=false causes Map, Pivot and other controls to not swallow events for nested controls.

If that doesn't help, have a look at the following Nokia Wiki article where the author ran into the same problem as you did and used Touch.FrameReported to get out of it @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Real-time_rotation_of_the_Windows_Phone_8_Map_Control

Comment: UseOptimizedManipulationRouting helps to raise only ManipulationCompleted event but Touch.FrameReported is really powerful and works in my case!