# Manipulation_started doesn't work on a map

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, dictionary

Hi to all I'm trying to set a listener for the ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta, ManipulationCompleted of a map to detect if the user drag a map around, but looks like none of those events are launched if I drag the map. If I set a tap listener for the map ManipulationStarted is correctly launched.
What I'm doing wrong?

xaml code:

```
<Controls:Map x:Name="myMap" 
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Loaded="myMap_Loaded"
                      ManipulationDelta="myMap_ManipulationDelta"
                      ManipulationCompleted="myMap_ManipulationCompleted"
                      ManipulationStarted="myMap_ManipulationStarted"
                      Tap="myMap_Tap">
```

code behind:

```
private void myMap_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Event:: MyMap_manipulationdelta");
}

private void myMap_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Event:: MyMap_manipulationcompleted");
}

private void myMap_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Event:: MyMap_manipulationstarted");
}

private void myMap_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Event:: MyMap_tap");
}
```

I'm on a normal page, no pivot or panorama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you won't be able to handle those events because Map control intercepts them. Although there is a property [UseOptimizedManipulationRouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting(v=vs.105).aspx), but as I've tested it - it doesn't help much in this situation.
I dont't know what you are trying to achieve, but if you don't need ManipulationDeltaEventArgs then maybe you consider using different events such as: MouseEnter, ResolveCompleted and CenterChanged.
If you need them then as [JustinAngel suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389426/how-to-know-when-map-control-was-first-manipulated) you can follow [these instructions](http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Real-time_rotation_of_the_Windows_Phone_8_Map_Control) and use Touch.FrameReported event for your purpose.

**EDIT** - code sample
If I've understood you properly, you would like to know when the User touches the Map, MouseEnter won't be the best choice as it will work only first time, then if mouse didn't leave the Map (user touched somewhere else), it won't fire again. Better solution here (following instructions above) can be such a code:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
   TouchPoint point = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(myMap);
   if (point.Action == TouchAction.Move && point.Position.Y > 0)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("User is Moving Finger over the Map!");
   }
}
```

Comment: I used the map control to implement a simple navigator, so the map will move together when the user's position chenges. I'm trying to detect if the map has been moved by the user, if so i want to stop the map to follow the user position. I think i cannot use CenterChanged (because it changes when the user position chanes) and I was not able to understand how to use UseOptimizedManipulationRouting and ResolveCompleted. I will give a try to MouseEnter, I've ignored it because I was thinking that it was only for SilverLight applications on PCs. 
any further advice is welcome :)

Comment: @JacopoGrassi If you want to detect if the User has touched the map, mouse enter wouldn't be the best choice. I've added a little sample code, maybe it will help you.

Comment: actually, i tried MouseEnter yesterday and it worked pretty well since the user have to touch another button to restart following his position if he touches the button MouseEnter will be launched next time the user move the map. but i think your solution it's more correct. thank you :)

Comment: @JacopoGrassi You are welcome. Just remember to handle those point.Action and point.Position correctly, a specialy this position - it depends on your Map position in the screen. I've used simple example where my map is at the bottom of the screen. Good Luck.